# Best way to initialize multiple menu items into a menu from a restaurant

Tags: java

My question is this,
 What would be the best way to store multiple restaurant menu items into a Menu class? I can think of so many ways, but I keep thinking there is a way to do it that's the "right way".
 I am currently storing them within an ArrayList, each with a price and name. Does this sound like a good idea? I suppose I just want to know how a professional programmer would approach storing a list of menu item objects. Would creating an object for each menu item be an effective technique? 
 This project is entirely personal and I have merely the foundation for the project.

Comment: Instead of insulting people, you should put effort in formulating your question correctly. in such a way that people can formulate something useful and also not waste their time.   anyways. bravo.  concerning that matter / with all respect,  I think its best you start by reading the rules of this site.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that you helped not in the slightest.. I apologize for wasting your precious time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a Menu class, I assume it would be a POJO class.
2. You have different restaurants, each restaurant has it's own menu.

**Solution:**
 Don't save multiple restaurant's menu in same menu class, have one object for one menu and yes it won't be inefficient to do so.

**Reason:**

1. The amount of data will be the same weather you store it in different objects or you save all in one. It is just that your data will be well managed and it will be independent of each other if you are having separate objects.
2. If you store all data in one object than suppose if you are not using menu of some restaurants, even then that data will stay in the memory. where as if there are separate objects, the menu that you are not using will be garbage collected. Now, this is why using multiple objects will not be inefficient.